# Move MSR partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning, system-reserved-partition

My system currently has the following partitions:

[image: Screenshot from GParted]

As shown, there are two recovery partitions. Running `reagentc /info` (as suggested [here](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/96389-why-two-recovery-partitions.html)) shows that `sdb5` is the one actually being used.

I would like to **delete** the unused recovery partition (`sdb1`) and **move** all other partitions (`sdb2`, `sdb3`, `sdb4`, `sdb5`) to the start of the disk, leaving all unallocated space as a contiguous block at the end (ready for Linux installation).

My problem is that GParted will not seem to let me move the MSR partition (`sdb3`) - the "resize/move" option is just greyed out.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The `Microsoft reserved partition` isn't unallocated space and serves a purpose. If you delete the `EFI System Partition`, you wouldn't be able to boot into Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't want to delete it. As I said, I want to delete the unused extra recovery partition (`sdb1`), and **move** the other partitions (including the EFI partition, `sdb2`, and Microsoft reserved partition, `sdb3`) to the start of the drive.

Comment: I always delete the MSR partition directly. It has done no harm to me in the past 5 years. Note: Don't mistakenly delete ESP.

Comment: I believe it's used for Bitlocker.

Comment: "wouldn't be able to boot into Windows" False. .efi is duplicated in C:\Windows\Boot\EFI, so may work if NTFS as ESP is supported by Ring -2 code and nvram points to look where to find EFI folder.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to Copy the MSR partition to an unallocated space block and then remove the original Source. It worked for me previously, altough I would recommend not to change the order of the partitions. So first remove the partition labeled Recovery, then move the EFI system partition and only then copy the MSR.
Hope it helps

Comment: I used AOMEI partition manager to create some free space in front of the msr partition. Used the copy function to duplicate it to the end of the disk, then deleted the original msr partition, and extended my EFI partition. It worked!

Answer (score 2):

Since gparted 0.33.0 you can move the msr as any usual partition if there is a free space to the left or to the right of the partition.